# The home page comes with a flickr token page

Tags: c#, .net, flicker

I tried this below code.
After `AuthCalcUrl` method the url is going to https://www.flickr.com/

```
flickr = new Flickr("xx....XX", "xx....XX");
string Frob = flickr.AuthGetFrob();
string url = flickr.AuthCalcUrl(Frob, AuthLevel.Write);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);

Auth auth = flickr.AuthGetToken(Frob);
flickr.AuthToken = auth.Token;
requestToken = flickr.OAuthGetRequestToken("oob");
string url1 = flickr.OAuthCalculateAuthorizationUrl(requestToken.Token, AuthLevel.Write);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url1);
```

Comment: Can you explain more, i did not understand your question.

Comment: Flickr goes to Flickr home page without getting token page